# flask\werkzeug: intercept a worker termination

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, werkzeug

Is there any way to execute some code just before a worker is turned off?
I'm not too confident on execution model of flask\werkzeug, the situation is this:

During the creation of flask application i start a deamon thread to do some external stuff (waiting on a queue essentially); i've setup this thread as demon because i don't want it to prevent the shut down of the worker running the flask application when it's needed.
there is my problem: i need to execute some clean up code just before the thread it's been killed by the worker, and my solution is to do those operations on a termination event (if any) of the worker

Comment: Workers being killed off is a feature of your WSGI server, not something that Flask / Werkzeug has any control over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With python you can use the *uwsgi.atexit* hook. The function *callback* will be executed before exit.

```
import uwsgi, os
from flask import Flask
app = Flask('demo')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World"

def callback():
    print "Worker %i exinting" % os.getpid()
uwsgi.atexit = callback
```